# Creating a calendar without reinventing the wheel

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

I want to have a calendar in my app where I can create events. It would, or course, probably be stupid for me to write my own calendar from scratch. I want to leverage existing tools.

It seems to me that Google Calendar API would probably be a good choice. What I want to do initially is just get a "Hello, World!" calendar going: I just want to embed a calendar in a web page. Ultimately, I want to be able to change the behavior of the calendar. For example, when you click on any certain day, I want it to take the user to a certain form as opposed to showing them a pop-up.

There is a lot of material in the Google Calendar API docs and I don't really know where to start. Nothing I've seen looks quite like what I want, which seems weird to me because this seems like a pretty common need.

Is someone who has done this sort of thing before able to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My needs ended up changing enough that creating my own calendar from scratch makes sense. The calendar I use won't end up looking much like Google Calendar.